# How to site Provisioning in office 365 (SharePoint online) by Custom

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

I want to do site provisioning (Custom), not using pnp starter kit, all should be done by custom.

I have custom list/ columns, custom look and content type.

How to package and how to deploy on o365

Answer (score 0):

you can provision site in the SharePoint Add-in model.

An article for your reference:
[Site provisioning in the SharePoint Add-in model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/site-provisioning-sharepoint-add-in)